# Parse ASCII hex dump for correct conversion to binary

Tags: linux, memory, binary, hex, hexdump

By default ***ASCII HEX*** memory dump produced by U-boot `md.b` (memory display) command contains additional column with corresponding ASCII text translation. Before converting ascii hex dump to binary, the extra stuff need be cleaned from dump. md.b can not produce dump without ascii table. When I converted raw hex dump containing ascii table, I've got output file are significantly  larger than it should be.

```
xxd -r -p input.txt output.bin
```

How to parse hex dump file to remove ascii table, to make correct ascii hex input for proper conversion to binary? Preferably with linux `xxd`.

**Edit:** part of hex dump. Note: large areas in the top and in the bottom of dump are empty, data is somewhere in the middle.

```
20000000: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
20000010: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
20000020: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
--------
20062270: 29 ef a3 43 3c ae 21 d8 25 ed 04 04 c0 cb 65 ad    )..C<.!.%.....e.
20062280: a5 60 19 98 65 ad 22 7d f2 14 5c bb 70 96 c7 6c    .`..e."}..\.p..l
20062290: 24 d0 fe 21 d0 48 f0 86 16 85 82 db 08 5a 67 c5    $..!.H.......Zg.
200622a0: 21 6f dc 6b a3 64 2b 53 64 98 15 27 46 d6 c1 39    !o.k.d+Sd..'F..9
200622b0: 59 ac ce 49 7c 0e be 00 7e cd da 8a ea fb 34 88    Y..I|...~.....4.
200622c0: e3 f3 fe b1 7b e9 16 b7 3a a2 6e 69 92 7b a7 a6    ....{...:.ni.{..
200622d0: a4 1e e8 c3 d1 58 b0 5a 25 cb 38 89 17 89 1f 27    .....X.Z%.8....'
200622e0: 8b ab 24 58 19 5d d6 1e 6c de a3 76 a1 c5 c4 0f    ..$X.]..l..v....
```

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you include the smallest sample input file that illustrates the problem. If you need to process as binary file, then you'll need to give us code or command that will generate a tiny one, and that we can they try to help solve your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

The following command provide correct conversion to binary:

```
xxd -r -seek -0x20000000 input.txt output.bin
```

---

`xxd -r -p` expects input in plain hexadecimal format, without addresses or ASCII.

`xxd -r` assumes that addresses are zero-based.

`xxd -r -seek -0x20000000` will seek to skip over regions not present in the dump (the first 0x20000000 = 536870912 bytes).

All credit goes to [lumato](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/64997/lumato).